# DefaultDocument suddenly not working on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, document, default

I have a website which has been running on IIS7 for about 2 months.  We have the default documents set up to load a default.asp page when users go to the domain with no page.  Suddenly this morning, I am getting errors and the default document will not load.  If I type the default.asp, the file loads just fine.

Error Info:
Module: DefaultDocumentModule 
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler: StaticFile 
Error Code: 0x80070002

here is a section from my applicationhost.config:

```
<system.webServer>

    <asp>
        <cache diskTemplateCacheDirectory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\ASP Compiled Templates" />
    </asp>

    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

    <globalModules>
        <add name="UriCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll" />
        <add name="FileCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachfile.dll" />
        <add name="TokenCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachtokn.dll" />
        <add name="HttpCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachhttp.dll" />
        <add name="StaticCompressionModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll" />
        <add name="DefaultDocumentModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll" />
        <add name="DirectoryListingModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\dirlist.dll" />
        <add name="ProtocolSupportModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\protsup.dll" />
        <add name="HttpRedirectionModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\redirect.dll" />
        <add name="ServerSideIncludeModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\iis_ssi.dll" />
        <add name="StaticFileModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\static.dll" />
        <add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\authanon.dll" />
        <add name="RequestFilteringModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\modrqflt.dll" />
        <add name="CustomErrorModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\custerr.dll" />
        <add name="HttpLoggingModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\loghttp.dll" />
        <add name="RequestMonitorModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\iisreqs.dll" />
        <add name="IsapiModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\isapi.dll" />
        <add name="IsapiFilterModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\filter.dll" />
        <add name="CgiModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cgi.dll" />
        <add name="FastCgiModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\iisfcgi.dll" />
        <add name="ManagedEngine" image="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\webengine.dll" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
        <add name="ConfigurationValidationModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\validcfg.dll" />
        <add name="ManagedEngine64" image="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\webengine.dll" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />
        <add name="RewriteModule" image="%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll" />
        <add name="ManagedEngineV4.0_32bit" image="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
        <add name="ManagedEngineV4.0_64bit" image="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
        <add name="WebDAVModule" image="%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\webdav.dll" />
        <add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\authsspi.dll" />
    </globalModules>
```

I have also verified that the modules physically exist on disk.  I am not aware of any changes on this server, and the default document has definitely been working up till yesterday.  Server is Windows Server 2008 x64 with IIS 7.0.

I've recycled the app pool, booted the server, removed and reentered the default documents.  the error looks like it cant find the default document module..

What else can I try?

Comment: Have you tried running Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 then restarting IIS and accessing the page? That should show you the exact path it's trying to read and failing. (As it looks like you know, 0x80070002 == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.)

Comment: I'm looking through the Process Monitor, but there's so much there.. I dont know what to look at.  can you help me out?  I put a filter on for Process Name = "w3wp.exe" and Result is not "SUCCESS".  Still getting hundreds of hits per second.  this is on a production web server. Should I filter on an operation, or are there other ways to limit so that I know what to look for?

Comment: BTW - it looks like iis adds a \web.config to the end of every request??  is that normal?  I see the path I'm trying to go to with the default.asp, but just before it accesses that page, it tries default.asp\web.config.  it does this for every file, and every time it returns a PATH NOT FOUND..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My coworker and I have been chasing this all morning and someone on IRC pointed us to the resolution.  Turns out that IIS was having trouble with the default document b/c the website root folder had gotten marked as Hidden.  Apparently, when the folder is Hidden, the default document module cannot find it and you get the ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND shown above.
We verified this behavior on a Dev server by setting the web root folder to Hidden and sure enough got the same error for the default document.  Removed the Hidden attribute and the default document loads correctly.

I have seen a lot of questions about this today, and no one has posted an answer that fit our problem.  I want to say thanks to whoever that was on IRC!  And hopefully this will help others to post it here.