# ASP.NET Handler "StaticFile" has a bad module "DefaultDocumentModule" in its module list

Tags: asp.net, iis, mindtouch

I'm attempting to install MindTouch Core onto IIS8. Installation works just fine, but then I see this message. What does it mean?

Please note that I've got ASP.NET installed fully so that can't be an issue. Also, it's not an issue with application pools, I've tried them all.

Here is the `web.config` file of the site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <clear/>
            <add name="PHP via FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" resourceType="Unspecified" scriptProcessor="D:\MindTouch\redist\php\php-cgi.exe"/>
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" preCondition=""/>            
        </handlers>
        <isapiFilters>
            <filter name="IsapiRewrite4" path="D:\MindTouch\web\bin\IsapiRewrite4.dll"/>
        </isapiFilters>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Review the investigation steps noted in this entry, review the comments and answer, and see if it doesn't narrow the problem down somewhat:
[DefaultDocument suddenly not working on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594829/defaultdocument-suddenly-not-working-on-iis7)

This article explains more about global modules:
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview